# Get JPL output into a string in Java

Tags: java, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

I'm using Prolog in java through JPL, I have some predicates with the format predicate:

```
format("Result ~p, ",[X]),
```

Using JPL in java the output of format goes to the console output in java, how can I retrieve this result into a string variable in java?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about JPL but can't you use [`sformat`](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/swi-prolog/sec-3.35.html#sformat/3) to format into a string variable, and then retrieve it via JPL ?

```
?- sformat(S, "Result ~p", [X]).
```